# Sql server 2012 replication scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

I am under a really specific scenario. I have a database on a customer's site and a website on Azure cloud that connects to that database.

User is on a 50mbit fiber but this is obviously slow. So I am thinking of implementing replication with SQL Server on the local Azure server.

Is there a way of implementing the reads from the replica but the writes on the main database (I am thinking about this so that I don't have to deal with merges and I don't really care about the write speed)? Moving everything to cloud is not an option as on site there are a lot of clients that are already connected.

Comment: are you trying to implement Replication to SQL Azure server ?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   Is there a way of implementing the reads from the replica but the writes on the main database (I am thinking about this so that I don't have to deal with merges and I don't really care about the write speed)?
>   Blockquote

Technically possible but probably not in your scenario. Bi directional transactional replication would be required, which isn't invisible to the app/website.